# ConnectivityManager returns true even if there are no active networks

Tags: java, android-studio, android-connectivitymanager

I am trying to detect if there are any active internet connections (WIFI or MOBILE INTERNET). The code is as follows:

```
private boolean haveNetwork() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean flag=false;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            for (Network network : connMgr.getAllNetworks()) {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(network);
                if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                } else if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    flag=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Log.d("flag", String.valueOf(flag)); //returns true even if there's no internet connection
        return flag;
    }
```

As the title says, my connection status always remains to be true, even if there is no internet connection

Comment: Is it `internet connections` or `your device connected` ? which one do you want to check?

Comment: I am trying to detect if internet is connected (through WIFI or MOBILE INTERNET).

Answer (score 0):

What you have currently will only tell you if there is either a mobile or Wi-Fi network tracked by ConnectivityManager, not whether you are connected to it or not.

Since you appear to be doing this synchronously, you want to use these two methods:

- [ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetwork()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getActiveNetwork())
- [ConnectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(Network network)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities(android.net.Network))

You can use this if you want to call ConnectivityManager synchronously by replacing your `for` loop.

```
Network activeNetwork = connMgr.getActiveNetwork();
if (null == activeNetwork) {
    return false;
}
NetworkCapabilities nc = connMgr.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork);
return nc.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET) 
    && nc.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NetworkCapabilities` as `NetworkInfo` is deprecated and check the `getLinkDownstreamBandwidthKbps()` is greater then 1kbps for 1g 32 kbps for at least 2g speed